# OGR SetAttributeFilter with multiple fields?

Tags: python, shapefile, fields-attributes, ogr, filter

I am trying to open a layer using OGR in Python and filter the features using [SetAttributeFilter()](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#filter-by-attribute) where two fields are greater than zero.

```
from osgeo import ogr

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
dataset = driver.Open(shpPath, 1)
layer = dataset.GetLayer()
layer.SetAttributeFilter('Field1 > 0 and Field2 > 0')
```

I have tried several different syntax and either get back 0 or all the records. I've tried:

```
layer.SetAttributeFilter('"Field1" > 0 and "Field2" > 0')
layer.SetAttributeFilter('(Field1 > 0) and (Field2 > 0)')
layer.SetAttributeFilter('Field1 > 0 AND Field2 > 0')
```

There are a few online examples that use "or" but not "and".

Comment: try with double quotes, "Field1 > 0 and Field2 > 0"

Comment: No, didn't work. I would be surprised if the whole string required quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem with your shapefile because the formulation is correct

```
source  = driver.Open("test.shp", 1) 
layer = source.GetLayer()
# numbers of records
len(layer)
43
# the fields of the shapefile
layerDef = layer.GetLayerDefn()
print([layerDef.GetFieldDefn(i).GetName() for i in range(layerDef.GetFieldCount())])
['DIP', 'DIP_DIR', 'RHR']
# first selection
layer.SetAttributeFilter("DIP_DIR > 180")
0
for feature in layer:
     print(feature.GetField("DIP"),"-",feature.GetField("DIP_DIR"))
38 - 215
30 - 190
45 - 196
60 - 202
# second selection
layer.SetAttributeFilter("DIP  < 40 and DIP_DIR > 180")
0
for feature in layer:
    print(feature.GetField("DIP"),"-",feature.GetField("DIP_DIR"))
38 - 215
30 - 190
```

Control with [GeoPandas](http://geopandas.org/) (much easier to use)

```
import geopandas as gpd
df = gpd.read_file("test.shp")
df.head()
    DIP   DIP_DIR RHR                    geometry
0   25      118   28  POINT (231123.5670821433 79120.62802018097)
1   35      116   26  POINT (235819.7952766526 78382.19670573555)
2   38      125   35  POINT (236338.8905571044 78355.38896824743)
3   40      105   15  POINT (236450.9956411457 79242.48137239969)
4   48      132   42  POINT (236312.0828196163 79386.26832801779)
# first selection
df.loc[df.DIP_DIR > 180]
    DIP   DIP_DIR RHR                    geometry
32   38      215  125  POINT (228991.6717607854 74399.93090419189)
37   30      190  100  POINT (229588.9440796326 75232.66634874046)
38   45      196  106  POINT (228377.1704327406 75014.43223223553)
40   60      202  112  POINT (228216.3746994076 73785.43857115674)
# second selection
df.loc[(df.DIP < 40) & (df.DIP_DIR >  180)]
    DIP   DIP_DIR RHR                    geometry
32   38      215  125  POINT (228991.6717607854 74399.93090419189)
37   30      190  100  POINT (229588.9440796326 75232.66634874046)
```

Comment: Thank you. You're right. I just created a dummy test and got 'Field1 > 0 and Field2 > 0' to work. My ShapeFile does have some NULL values which I thought might be the problem, but I guess not because the following is working with my test: 'Field1 is not null and Field2 is not null'